# Could a spacecraft dock with the voyager 1?

Tags: space, nasa

Is the Voyager 1 (or any similar exploration spacecraft) equipped with the ability for space to dock with it (attach to it)?

Hypothetically, if a voyager or similar spacecraft were in Earth's orbit, could a NASA spacecraft dock with it in a similar fashion as it would the ISS?

Answer (score 1):

Building spacecraft is an exceedingly difficult task. Every gram of extra weight makes it harder and more expensive to launch your ship. So nothing is included on spaceships unless absolutely necessary. (At this point someone is going to point out the [record](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voyager_Golden_Record) attached to the Voyagers: this was **necessary** for PR purposes. :-)

Anyhow, it is exceedingly unlikely that we or any alien species is every going to see either of the Voyagers again, so building any docking facility would have added weight for no good reason.

The word "docking" implies access to the interior of the satellite, as in docking with the ISS. However there is no "inside" of Voyager, or indeed most unmanned spacecraft, as it's packed solid with kit. However if you use the word in the broader sense you could argue that the Hubble telescope has docking facilities so astronauts can service it.

Comment: Voyager 1 was presumably attached to the interior of the launch vehicle somehow. Maybe the hypothetical alien/NASA scientists could make use of those attachment fittings to design a coupling to attach Voyager 1 to another spacecraft? I guess the lack of alignment and locking elements would pose a challenge.

Comment: In addition opening it would probably void the warranty.

Answer (score 0):

Its not a *Star Trek* universe. In real world, we need standardized docking ports from both vessels which is almost impossible with two unknown races' vessels.

Plus, Voyager is an unmanned space probe with which there's no need of docking port. So, it doesn't have one.